# svn irksomeness ... summarize differences between HEAD and older, non-working copy?

Tags: svn, diff

How can I summarize changes between the current revision of a source tree in SVN and a copy of the source tree that is about one month old that has had all the .svn files removed?

I made this a working copy by doing a --depth=empty checkout, copying files into empty directory, and then doing svn add *. Only about 20% of the files should have changed. I can't seem to figure out an incantation to get a diff summary.

svn diff --summarize looks promising but it says "can only compare repository to repository"?

Can someone assist before I scratch a whole in the top of my head? :-)

```
             ... hippo-dancer
```

Answer (score 0):

Summarize the changes in what way?

You can use a wide variety of `diff` commands that can show you the differences between the two directories. What OS are you on? Take a look at [Beyond Compare](http://scootersoftware.com). It's a personal favorite of mine.

Beyond that, there isn't much else you can do. Those `.svn` directories are there for a reason. They keep track of changes, revisions, and all sorts of other information. They should never be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Unversion old WC was, in common, wrong - with WC metadata you can identify source URL and revision. But, now, if --summarize works only with URLs, you have  to... create second URL as "some branch" from unversioned source, yes?

Short PseudoGuide:

```
svn copy .../trunk .../tempbranch
mkdir newWC
cd newWC
svn co .../tempbranch .
<copy from unversioned locations, sync trees, don't touch .svn>
svn ci -m "Sync with old sources"
svn diff --summarize .../trunk .../tempbranch
```